# Transfer a specific function to VBA code

Tags: vba, text, if-statement, cells

I need help transferring a function to VBA code, can anyone help me?

Here is the function:

```
=IF(H4&I4&J4="TEXT"&"TEXT"&"TEXT";"TEXT";
IF(J4&I4="TEXT"&"TEXT";H4;
IF(H4&J4="TEXT"&"TEXT";I4;
IF(H4&I4="TEXT"&"TEXT";J4;
IF(J4="TEXT";(H4+I4)/2;IF(I4="TEXT";(H4+J4)/2;
IF(H4="TEXT";(I4+J4)/2;(H4+I4+J4)/3))))))
```

I tried to write something like this in VBA, but it did not work. . . . . . .  .

```
If Cells(H4) and Cells (I4) and Cells (J4) = "TEXT". Then
```

Comment: have you tried using the macro recorder for this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to understand the formula. What are you trying to do?

Regarding comparing the text of cell you have, use VBA Code like this

```
Range("H4").Value = "TEXT"
```

So `If Cells(H4) and Cells (I4) and Cells (J4) = "TEXT" Then` becomes

```
If Range("H4").Value = "TEXT" And _
Range("I4").Value = "TEXT" And _
Range("J4").Value = "TEXT" Then
    '~~> Do Something
End If
```

The above code can also be written as

```
Dim strString As String

strString = Range("H4").Value & Range("I4").Value & Range("J4").Value

If strString = "TEXTTEXTTEXT" Then
    '~~> Do Something
End If
```

Comment: The function that I attached came from the formula bar in excel, that´s probably why you do not understand? But now i want to transfer the function from the formula bar to VBA code. I think i where able to figure it out with your help, though. Thank U!!